# How to output a List of numbers in odd and even? C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I might be way off base here but this code on the MS site doesn't work for me when I modified it a little. Sorry its almost 2am. What variable should the int be? The program crashes stating "Specified cast is not valid."

```
ArrayList OddEven = new ArrayList();

            foreach (int i in lbList.Items)
            OddEven.Add(i);
            foreach (int i in OddEven)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    lbEven.Items.Add(i);
                else
                    lbOdd.Items.Add(i);
            }
```

Comment: You could use 'var' instead of 'int', this is all I could tell because there's no definition of lbList in your code. BTW it's 11 AM in my place :D

Comment: Supply the entire code segment, like where lblist is declared

Comment: Can you get your computer to output lbList.Items.GetType().ToString() - then we'll know what type we're dealing with and can advise.

Comment: unfortunate that this kind of questions gets upvotes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lbList.Items` are probably `strings` and an implicit cast to `int` doesn't exist.
Try this:

```
ArrayList OddEven = new ArrayList();

foreach (var i in lbList.Items)
  OddEven.Add(int.Parse(i.ToString()));

foreach (int i in OddEven)
{
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    lbEven.Items.Add(i);
  else
    lbOdd.Items.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: The int.Parse(i);  is red underlined, Saying there invalid arguments

Comment: oh you updated it. Lets have a look.

Comment: You updated your code so I too had to... :)

Comment: I wish it worked but it still states the int.Parse has invalid arguments. Sorry its so vague there. Also i % 2 ==0 became underlined

Comment: OK... Try it now. (Tested and working). The first solution I wrote (before your code change) also works.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Now I will try to get some sleep. I will try to wrap my head around it properly tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that lbList, lbEven and lbOdd are ListBoxes, you seem to be trying to cast a ListBoxItem to an int. I'm surprised this even compiles because the Add() method of the Items collection takes either a new ListBoxItem or a string, not an int. You'll have to post a bit more info. With that said, the basic logic using the modulo operator is correct, you're just trying to stuff the output into the wrong thing. How would you like to display your output?

Comment: You are correct. The input is from a listbox and the odd and even numbers will be displayed in separate listboxes also after the array has checked them all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your lbList is a ListBox or DropdownList

```
foreach (ListItem item in lbList.Items)
{
     int i = int32.Parse(item.Text);
     if (i % 2 == 0)
        lbEven.Items.Add(i);
     else
        lbOdd.Items.Add(i);
}
```

### Update

In Winforms, ListBox.Items returns `ObjectCollection`, each item in the list will be `Object`

```
foreach (object item in lbList.Items)
{
     int i = Convert.ToInt32(item);
     if (i % 2 == 0)
        lbEven.Items.Add(i);
     else
        lbOdd.Items.Add(i);
}
```

You can also do

```
foreach (var item in lbList.Items)
{
     int i = Convert.ToInt32(item);
     if (i % 2 == 0)
        lbEven.Items.Add(i);
     else
        lbOdd.Items.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: ListItem is not that colour in my VS. Do I need to add another System?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
lbList.Items.ToList<string>().ForEach(item => 
     {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(item);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            lbEven.Items.Add(i);
        else
            lbOdd.Items.Add(i);
    });
```